# Why does this python code produce an error:?

Tags: string, python-3.x, concatenation

Basically in python 3.0 I tried to use two %s string substitutes and concatenate it. However, it seems to produce an error.

**CODE**

```
 print "%s"+"%s" %("John", "rows")
```

I am new to programming so I would be thankful if I could get a simple explanation.
Thanks

Comment: Please put code in the question and not in the title. It's really hard to read there.

Comment: Python 3x does not support `print "as a statement"`; the former will never be valid syntax, and it should be written as `print("as a function")`. Of course, make sure to post a SSCCE and convey complete useful information (hint: "it doesn't work" is not acceptable level of detail between programmers).

Comment: try and put `"%s%s"` instead of the `"%s" + "%s"`.  Does it resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), which appears to be the language that line of code was written in (you treated `print` as a statement), you will get an error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

This is because the interpreter attempts to put both of the arguments into the latter string, due to the order of operations. Thus, simply wrap the string with parentheses and the code will run:

```
>>> print ("%s"+"%s") %("John", "rows")
Johnrows
>>>
```